# List snapshots of a lxd container

Tags: lxd

After creating a few snapshots in a lxd container using `lxc snapshot` I cannot find a way to list those snapshots. `lxc list` lists only containers, not the snapshots of each container. How can I list the names of all snapshots of a container? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can list the snapshots for a container named `example` with:

```
lxc info example --verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
lxc info container
```

If you use ZFS for storage

```
zfs list -t snapshot
```